# Pandas DataFrame - dictionary in rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Source of DataFrame is a list of dicts like -
`ls = [{'fileName': 'file_01', 'col1': {'key1': 'value1a', 'key2': 'value1b'}}, {'fileName': 'file_02', 'col1': {'key1': 'value2a', 'key2': 'value2b', 'key3':'value2c'}}, {'fileName': 'file_03', 'col1': {'key1': 'value3a', 'key3': 'value3c'}}]`

DataFrame created as
`df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['fileName', 'col1'])`

Pandas DataFrame `df` looks like -

```
fileName     col1 
file_01      {'key1':value1a, 'key2':value1b}
file_02      {'key1':value2a, 'key2':value2b, 'key3':value2c}
file_03      {'key1':value3a, 'key3':value3c}
```

How can I convert this to look like -

```
fileName     key1      key2      key3
file_01      value1a   value1b 
file_02      value2a   value2b   value2c
file_03      value3a             value3c
```

I tried -
`df = pd.concat([df['fileName'], pd.get_dummies(df['col1'].apply(pd.Series))], axis=1)`

I see results in some cases like -

```
fileName     key1_value1a     key1_value2a     key1_value3a
file_01      value1a           
file_02                       value2a   
file_03                                        value3a
```

Comment: Please provide some example data in a format that is easy for people to use. How is that DataFrame being created? Odds are there's a way to create the columns directly, without storing the dictionaries first.

Comment: @AMC Edited question based on your input. The accepted answer helps achieve the desired results from the original step. Do you see a better approach to avoid the issue at the time of DataFrame creation itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
In [40]: pd.concat([df['fileName'], pd.json_normalize(df['col1'])],axis=1)      
Out[40]: 
   fileName     key1     key2     key3
0   file_01  value1a  value1b      NaN
1   file_02  value2a  value2b  value2c
2   file_03  value3a      NaN  value3c
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df[['fileName']], pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].to_list())], axis=1)
```

The above will work if `{'key1':value1a, 'key2':value1b}, {'key1':value2a, 'key2':value2b, 'key3':value2c}, ...` are of type `dict`

This solution will also work, but the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086804/2825570) provided by @Vorsprung looks nice.

Comment: yes they are of type `dict`. I tried `df1 = pd.concat([df[['fileName']], pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].values))`, but I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: There was a missing `]`. `df1 = pd.concat([df[['fileName']], pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].values)])` gives a new DataFrame with columns `fileName` and `0`. `0` has no values.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works as well. Up voted the same. However, I used the solution provided in the accepted answer earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df['fileName'], df['col1'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

`df['col1'].apply(pd.Series)` split dict into seperate columns.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works as well. Up voted the same. However, I used the solution provided in the accepted answer earlier.

Comment: In your case, if you care about the performance it's better to use the `pd.json_normalize()` method. The use of `apply()` method is flexible though.